# Symfony 5 and update PHP 8.0.3

Tags: php, symfony

I'm very disappointed because I wanted update php 8 on my laptop from php 7.4, I did everything right, but when i run a Symfony project and Symfony server, that show this message:

> `Fatal error: Composer detected issues in your platform: Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 8.0.0". You are running 5.6.40. in C:\Users\decli\Desktop\projects\PHP Language Projetcts\Symfony-projects\mysocialnetwok\vendor\composer\platform_check.php on line 25`

I don't understand why, I searched on Google but nothing on this issue. And also, when I type `symfony php --version`, now I'm on 5.6.40 whereas before it everything was ok, and now i can't create un symfony new project.

Sorry i'm not a great dev, but right now, it's too strange for me.

[image]

[image]

Comment: To be fair here this isn't really a Symfony problem. This is an upgrade to PHP on a Windows machine issue.

Comment: Please stop flooding with emoji's .. how did you go through the upgrade process? What site showed you how to do it? What steps did you take?

Comment: Sorry for emoji's, i have 46 year so i would like to be young man again again and again .
So i've download the windows version of php 8.0.3, i've enter the link directory in path, and in console it's ok, i have php 8.0.3 version, i've also re-install composer with php8, but since symphony don't work or it's ma machine, here the video but sorry it's in French 
https://youtu.be/Ae-XwrvYuPw

Comment: when i don't use symfony cli but instead composer for create symfony/skeleton, then i use php server and it's ok

Comment: I find informations on https://github.com/symfony/cli/issues/165

Comment: I'm sorry that I can't help you more. I was trying to edit your post to get you in front of the Windows tag to hopefully get you some help.

Comment: Thank you very much, i tried to post on french forum, but no solution too, so for the moment i'm come back at 7.4 php version because it's more easy to use, but i'm a little disappointed of course ! there are many good update with PHP8 and i should to find any solutions ... later. after many years on Linux and Mac, i'm come back on windows And I'm already starting to regret it ! or the problem it's me, and i need to improve.
But thank you very much again, and sorry for my bad English ;-)

Comment: "You are running 5.6.40" - anything unclear about this? That does not sound like you are using PHP 8

Answer (score 0):

So the only solution i have found for the moment, it's add a .php-version at root with the php version I want to use, in this case 8.0.3, and it's ok but by default symfony use the 5.6.4 version and i don't know how to change it.
Thanks